# How to maintain Galaxy S2 screen active (Android OS)?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, setting

In Samsung Galaxy S2, where can I find the option to keep screen active? I've already searched through **Menu->Configuration->Application->Development** (and every other menu), but the **Development** option is missing in Application view (the view is a kind of application manager, not option settings).

I know that there is a lot of issues about keeping the amoled display active (i.e. pixel burn), but I'm in really need of this feature, as it is becoming very anoying to tap my device screen every time it is close to turn inactive.

Bellow is my **Setting->Developer Options** screen-shot:

[image]

Special Note: I've ready somewhere that the manufacturers had removed the option to keep screen active. Is this a true information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check settings -> developer options

Comment: Hi nandeesh, thanks for the reply. A already took a look in this option, but haven't found anything. I've posted the images of settings->developer options. Its in Pt-Br language, but I think you can check it without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Setting the value programmatically using below code

```
Settings.System.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),Settings.System.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN,(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC | BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB));
```

Comment: keep a different app, i am not saying you add it in your app. So whenever you are developing run this app , you can disable this by making the value 0

Comment: Thanks again nandeesh. Man, this should not help... I want the screen to test/develop apps, not as a feature of the developed/tested app. ;)

Comment: Well as I said, make a different app, just to toggle this button. Toggle it when developing

Comment: Hmm, sounds to be a solution. But I'm in really need to dev an app just to setup this? It isn't so hard, but does Samsung Galaxy realy not provide such option? Thanks!